# String Split and save into ArrayList in JAVA7

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, java-7

I have a string wherein I need to split it and store in an ArrayList as seen below; All these using Java7.

The below is the input for my program;

```
String inputStr = "ABC:DONE:07JAN90:1234:00001111:U:1234567:9632587:4561230:EC:IN:4815263:3621547:0314783)";
```

What I am trying to achieve here is an ArrayList as seen below after its grouped.

```
   "List" : [ 
    {
    1234567,
    4815263
    },
    {
     9632587,
    3621547
    },
     {
     4561230,
     0314783
     }
    ]
```

I have a sample code written but that doesn't seem to group the elementB into the list. How can we do the grouping of both the elements into a List.

Sample Code:

```
    String splitStringNeeded = "ABC:DONE:07JAN90:1352:00009279:U:1234567:9632587:4561230:EC:GB:4815263:3621547:0314783)";
            
    String[] vElements = splitStringNeeded.split(":");
    String[] grpV = Arrays.copyOfRange(vElements, 6,10 );
    String[] grpT = Arrays.copyOfRange(vElements, 12, vElements.length);
        
    List<String> groupedV = Arrays.asList(grpV);
    List<String> groupedT = Arrays.asList(grpT);
    
    for(String splitV : groupedV){
        for(String splitT : groupedT){
        
            System.out.println(splitV);
            System.out.println(splitT);
            break;
        
        }
    }
```

I am getting the below output where elementB does not change but repeats itself. Can someone please guide

```
"List" : [ 
    {
    1234567,
    4815263
    },
    {
     9632587,
    4815263
    },
     {
     4561230,
     4815263
     }
    ]
```

We can consider even the below inputs:

```
ABC:DONE:07JAN90:1352:00009279:U:1234567:9632587:0:EC:GB:4815263:3621547

ABC:DONE:07JAN90:1352:00009279:U:1234567:0:0:EC:GB:4815263
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you are doing. Certainly the comparison with `"0"` will never match since that isn't in your input. There is no reason to create new ArrayLists just to immediately overwrite them with the results of calling Arrays.asList. I would suggest you try to debug your code and find out what it is doing. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I have now edited my sample program. I am trying to group them into a list

Answer (score 1):

I have just modified the nested for loop in your sample code to a single for loop
Of course there are few un-knows such as 
Does your Source string always follow same pattern as you have displayed 
The length of the lists **groupedV** and **groupedT** are they always of same length etc. which is not considered

```
String splitStringNeeded = "ABC:DONE:07JAN90:1352:00009279:U:1234567:9632587:4561230:EC:GB:4815263:3621547:0314783";

/* Additional code for dynamic allocation of indexes
int indexU = splitStringNeeded.indexOf("U:");
int indexOfGb = splitStringNeeded.indexOf("EC:GB:");
System.out.println("Index of U "+indexU);
System.out.println("Index of GB "+indexOfGb);
String sub1 = splitStringNeeded.substring(indexU+2, indexOfGb-1);
System.out.println("Substring 1 = "+sub1);
String sub2 = splitStringNeeded.substring(indexOfGb+6, splitStringNeeded.length());
System.out.println("Substring 2 = "+sub2);
    //Additional code for dynamic allocation of indexes
*/

String[] vElements = splitStringNeeded.split(":");

String[] grpV = Arrays.copyOfRange(vElements, 6, 9);
String[] grpT = Arrays.copyOfRange(vElements, 11, vElements.length);

List<String> groupedV = Arrays.asList(grpV);
List<String> groupedT = Arrays.asList(grpT);

if(groupedV.size() == groupedT.size()) {
    for(int i=0; i<groupedV.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(groupedV.get(i));
        System.out.println(groupedT.get(i));
    }
}
/*for (String splitV : groupedV) {
    for (String splitT : groupedT) {
        if (!splitV.equals("0")) {
            System.out.println(splitV);
            System.out.println(splitT);
            break;
        }
    }
}*/
```

I have added the commented code to dynamically pick the index values instead of hard coding like 6,10,12

if you un-comment the first commented block the output will be like below

```
Index of U 31
Index of GB 57
Substring 1 = 1234567:9632587:4561230
Substring 2 = 4815263:3621547:0314783
1234567
4815263
9632587
3621547
4561230
0314783
```

Comment: That was the output i was expecting. But yeah the values i have hardcoded for example purpose. there can be values like 

`ABC:DONE:07JAN90:1352:00009279:U:1234567:9632587:0:EC:GB:4815263:3621547`
 and 
`ABC:DONE:07JAN90:1352:00009279:U:1234567:0:0:EC:GB:4815263`

Thats why i have added the check `splitV.equals("0")`